The breakdown of a regex
.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
can someone explain what this means I know it is a regular expression but I dont understand what it is doing and what it means and what the purpose is. Its currently in my tooltip.

There are tools to breakdown the regex

This regex allows you to add commas to a number to make it more readable.
The .replace() method uses this regex to add commas to a number. For example, transform 1000000 into 1,000,000.
Exemple:


let number = "1000000";
let formattedNumber = number.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
console.log(formattedNumber);  // Affiche : "1,000,000";




I want my regular expression (  title={
Object.doc_count
? Object.doc_count
" Home-net Mismatches"
: "No Data Found"
}  ) to be a variable is that possible

@NateBrown what do you mean?

@NateBrown, ( title={ Object.doc_count ? Object.doc_count " Home-net Mismatches" : "No Data Found" } ) is not a regex

@NateBrown please don't ask questions in comments on an answer. Perhaps ask a brand new question where you can clearly explain what you want, show your attempts and explain any problems.
